# Embedded jetty server stream data continuously

Tags: java, ajax, jetty, embedded-jetty

Apologies if the question is duplicate, I tried to look for it but could not get any idea.
My scenario is something like this:

- I have an embedded jetty server running in a java application with few handlers producing some html pages.
- I have a log file in the server which I would like to display continuously updating on the browser
- I am quite new to this stuff, can anyone guide me how to go about the browser getting the livestream of the growing text logs?

This might be very simple to achieve but any pointers will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Look at comet, it's a push mechanism allowing you to send messages from the server to the browser.

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Cometd+(aka+Bayeux)

Comment: You can also use the official website: [cometd.org](http://cometd.org/) .  Note: there is overlap in developers between both projects (Jetty & CometD) so support between both is top notch.